# Adding new Excel files to MS Access database as they come in

Tags: database, ms-access, excel, import, vba

I am in the situation where I have a questionnaire that is basically just a plain excel spreadsheet with two columns:

- one column with the questions and
- a second column next to it where users can fill in their answers.

Each respondent has been sent a copy of the file and they will email back their files individually over a long time period. I can't wait until i have all files back; instead i would like to collect (and use) the data in Access as the files come in.

Two questions:

1. What is the best set up in terms of the manual steps required when a new datafile comes in. Can one just save the file in a specific folder and somehow have the column (column B) with responses "automatically" added to the main database? If not fully automatically, what could be done with just a few manual steps involved?
2. I realize that the shape of the questionnaire is not ideal (variables are in rows, not in columns). What's the best way to deal with that?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

PS: I'be open to (simple) alternatives, if Access is not the best choice for this. Analysis of the data will be done in Excel again in the end.

**Update, to clarify the questions below:**

1) In the short - medium term, we are expecting 50-100 replies. In the long term, it will be more as, people will be asked to send updates when their situation changes - these will have to be added as new entries with a new date attached to them. i.e. it will be a continuous process with a few answers coming in every few weeks.

2) There are 80 questions on the questionnaire.

3) The Excel files come back as email attachments.

4) I was contemplating using Acess, as I thought it will a) makeit a bit cleaner and less error prone,   especially as project managers might change in the future, b) allow for better handling of the data, as it will have to be mashed up and reshaped in different ways for the anlysis (e.g. it has to be un-pivoted, which i don't even know if excel can do), and c) i thought it it would give us more flexibility in the future when it comes to using different tools for analysis. i.e. each tool can just query the database. I am open for other  suggestions, including Excel-only solutions, if that makes it easier, though.

5) I envision the base table to have all the 80 variables in different columns, and the answers as rows (i.e. each new colum that comes with each excel file will need to be transposed and added as    a new row). There will be other data tables with the same primary key as the row identifier in this table.

6) I havn't worked on the  analysis part yet, but i know that it will require a lot of reshaping    and merging of data sets.

Comment: Could you not just build the questionnaire in an Access form and ask that people complete it there?  That way you would be capturing the source data in the right place..just a thought.

Comment: Hi Mat, Great suggestion - thanks!. I would have done it that way, if the mailing hadn't started already before i took on the project...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 - Questions**

You do not provide enough information to allow any one to give you pointers.  Some initial questions:

- How many questionaires are you expecting: 10, 100, 1000?
- How many questions are there per questionaire?
- How are the questionaires reaching you?  You say "email back".  Does this mean as an attachment or as a table in the body of the email.
- You say the data is arriving as Excel files and you intend to do the analysis in Excel.  Why are you storing the answers in Access?  I am not saying you are wrong to store the results in Access; I just want to be convinced you have a reason.
- Have you designed the planned table structure for Access?
- Have you designed the structure of the Excel workbook(s) on which you will perform the analysis?

Comment: Thanks, Tony. Good questions. I'll answer them in turn:

Comment: See my edits to the question. Hope these help. Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2**

Firstly, I should say that I agree with Mat.  I am not an expert on questionnaires but my understanding is that there are companies that will host online questionnaires and provide the results in a convenient form.

Most of the rest of this answer assumes it is too late to consider an online questionnaire or you have, for whatever reason, rejected that approach.

An Access project is, to a degree, self-documenting. You can look at its list of tables and see that Table 1 has columns A, B and C. If created properly you can see the relationships between tables.  With an Excel workbook you just have a number of worksheets which can contain anything.  There is no automatic documentation.

However, with both Excel and Access the author **can** create complete documentation that explains each table, worksheet, report and macro.  If this project is going to last indefinitely and have a succession of project managers, such documentation will be essential.  I can tell you from bitter experience that trying to understand a complex Access project or Excel workbook that you have inherited without proper documentation is at best difficult and at worst impossible.

Don’t even start this unless you plan to create and maintain proper documentation.  I do not mean: “We will knock up something when we have finished.”  Once it is finished, people will be moving onto their next projects and will have little time for boring stuff like documentation.  After the event documentation also loses all the decisions and the reasons for those decisions.  The next team is left wondering why their predecessors did it that way.  The reason will not matter in many cases but I have seen a product destroyed by a new team removing “unnecessary complexity” they did not understand.  I always kept a notebook in which I recorded what I was doing and why during the day.  I encouraged my staff to do the same.  I insisted something for the project log every week.  The level of detail depends on the project.  The question I asked myself was: “If I had just inherited this project, what happened during the last week that I would need to know?”  This was in addition to an up-to-date specification for each component.

Sorry, I will get off my hobby-horse.

“In the short - medium term, we are expecting 50-100 replies. In the long term, it will be more as, people will be asked to send updates when their situation changes - these will have to be added as new entries with a new date attached to them.”

If you are going to keep a history of answers then Access will probably be a better repository than Excel.  However, who is going to maintain the Access project and the central Excel workbooks?  Access does not operate in the same way as Excel.  Access VBA is not quite the same as Excel VBA.  This will not matter if you are employing professionals experienced in both Access and Excel.  But if you are employing amateurs who are picking up the necessary skills on the job then using both Access and Excel will increase what they have to learn and the likelihood that they will get confused.

If there are only 100 people/organisations submitting responses, you could merge responses and maintain one workbook per respondent to create something like:

```
          Answers  -->
Question  1May2014  20Jun2014  7Nov2014
Aaaaaa      aa         bb        cc
Bbbbbb      dd         ee        ff
```

I am not necessarily recommending an Excel approach but it will have benefits in some circumstances.  Personally, unless I was using professional programmers, I would start with an Excel only solution until I knew why I needed Access.

“I envision the base table to have all the 80 variables in different columns, and the answers as rows (i.e. each new colum that comes with each excel file will need to be transposed and added as a new row).”  I interpret this to mean a row will contain:

- Respondent identifier
- Date
- Answer to Q1
- Answer to Q2
- :      :
- Answer to Q80.

My Access is very rusty.  Is there a way of accessing attribute “Answer to Q(n)” or are you going to need 80 statements to move answers in and out?  I hope there is no possibility of new questions.  I found updating the database when a row changed a pain.  I always favoured small rows such as:

- Respondent identifier
- Date
- Question number
- Answer

There are disadvantages to having lots of small rows but I always found the advantages outweighed them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer (and apologies for the late reply). Good point about the documentation. Will consider your suggestion about using smaller rows... I guess it also depends on the method that will be used to input the raw data into the database.